# kernel32 module not found

Tags: python, matlab, kernel32

Running pymatlab , more specifically the command  `session = pymatlab.session_factory()` results in

> Exception AttributeError: "'MatlabSession' object has no attribute
>   'engine'" in > ignored

The suggested solution here

[Running MATLAB from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20292585/running-matlab-from-python)

is to change line 51 in `C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymatlab\sessionfactory.py` from

```
MatlabSession(path=basedir,bufsize=output_buffer_size)
```

to :

```
MatlabSession(basedir,bufsize=output_buffer_size)
```

which I did.

However, another problem now arises in the module ctypes:

```
C:\Python27\lib\ctypes\__init__.pyc in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error)
    363 
    364         if handle is None:
--> 365             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    366         else:
    367             self._handle = handle

WindowsError: [Error 126] The specified module could not be found
```

Putting a breakpoint reveals that the module in question is `kernel32`.

Any suggestion what to do ? I am running Windows 8 and 64-bit Python 2.7

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

change line 56 in matlab.py

replace 'glnxa64' to 'win32'