# Error when getvalue() with pymatlab

Tags: python, matlab

I am trying to call matlab from python with pymatlab.

My env is python 2.7 32bit, pymatlab 0.2.3, matlab 2010b 32bit, and windows7 64bit.

I have modified pymatlab codes to fix some minor bugs, like [Running MATLAB from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20292585/running-matlab-from-python)

However, I still cannot get value from matlab session:

```
matlab_session.run('ccc = [1.0,2.0]')
matlab_session.getvalue('ccc')
```

returns error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pymatlab\matlab.py", line 91, in getvalue
ndims = self.mx.mxGetNumberOfDimensions(mx)
WindowsError: exception: access violation reading 0x00000010
```

Comment: FYI, there is an official MATLAB API for Python: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab-engine-for-python.html

Comment: I know.... but my Matlab version is 2012b